# app unstable with memory pressure issues, memory history is not clear

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management

after enabling addressSanitizer debugger support, my app crashes after loading the first view controller. This is a collection view with bunch of images. I use Nuke to load the images. Can someone help me understand what this memory history is saying?

Reference(1113,0x1f775000) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x8bc6000
==1113==__sanitizer_mz_destroy() called -- ignoring
Reference(1113,0x1f775000) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0xbb80000
==1113==__sanitizer_mz_destroy() called -- ignoring
Reference(1113,0x1f775000) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x8bc4000
==1113==__sanitizer_mz_destroy() called -- ignoring
(lldb) ivars 0x8bc6000
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb) memory history 0x8bc6000
  thread #4294967295: tid = 0x001b, 0x002f02c8 libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib`wrap_malloc_create_zone + 172, name = 'Memory allocated at'
    frame #0: 0x002f02c8 libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib`wrap_malloc_create_zone + 172
    frame #1: 0x349f824c IMGSGX543GLDriver`glrAllocVendorMallocZones + 36
    frame #2: 0x349f5ec2 IMGSGX543GLDriver`gldInitializeLibrary + 242
    frame #3: 0x27522b1e libGFXShared.dylib`gfxInitializeLibrary + 1278
    frame #4: 0x3514d52c GLEngine`gliInitializeLibrary + 44
    frame #5: 0x27578a60 OpenGLES`eagl_init + 472
    frame #6: 0x27578666 OpenGLES`-[EAGLSharegroup initWithAPI:sharedWithCompute:] + 102
    frame #7: 0x27577a20 OpenGLES`-[EAGLContext commonInitWithAPI:properties:] + 240
    frame #8: 0x27e26974 QuartzCore`CAEAGLContextCreate + 204
    frame #9: 0x27e06174 QuartzCore`CA::CG::IOSurfaceRenderer::acquire(CA::CG::IOSurfaceDrawable&, CA::CG::IOSurfaceRenderer**, unsigned int, bool) + 556
    frame #10: 0x27e05eac QuartzCore`CA::CG::Queue::render_callback(void*) + 48
    frame #11: 0x002ef53a libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib`asan_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 200
    frame #12: 0x02c4f5a8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 2012
    frame #13: 0x02c47ef6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 282
    frame #14: 0x02c50fe4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1788
    frame #15: 0x02c508e4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 100
    frame #16: 0x258f7b26 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1022
    frame #17: 0x258f7716 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 6

Comment: try check your memory usage using instrument. Normally downloading multiple images will cause huge usage of memory if not using cache. and it keep increasing. Please refer steps to use instruments here https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Comment: It would be better if you just showed your code. What are you doing with these images?